# Oracle Instant Client is installed and the php_oci8 is enabled, but php throws: Call to undefined function oci_connect()

Tags: php, database, oracle, ubuntu, homestead

I try to get to work my PHP server and an Oracle database (12c). The problem is that PHP throws this error:

> Call to undefined function oci_connect()

After reading a few posts, I installed Oracle Instant Client. The environment is an Ubuntu, to be precise its a Laravel Homestead vagrant box. The `sqlplus` connect is working, so I can log in into the database, but PHP still doesn't find the `oci_connect()` function. I also enabled the `php_oci8.dll`.

Is there any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Post you environment variables too (.e.g ORACLE_HOME, etc) and where you put those variables + the location (paths) of `instant_client` you specified

Comment: Please check `phpinfo()` to see if the OCI8 library is actually available in your script environment.

Comment: I followed these instructions:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Oracle%20Instant%20Client